# which Local relational Data Base for Flutter windows app after 2.10 stable version. Should Use?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows, flutter-datatable

Hello There I want to know is there any way to implement the local relational database for the **windows Flutter app**. because the **flutter 2.10** is here with windows stable..

one of my app have **Floor database** used for relational database for **IOS and ANDROID** version of my app.

now I want to create the same app for windows version but Floor is not supported flutter windows.

Now I'm stuck until I get suitable suggestion..

I have seen **Hive** on **Pub.dev** many **nonSql database**.. but I want a **relational database**..

Answer (score 2):

SQLite should work fine on Windows:

[sqflite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

They have an [example project](https://github.com/alextekartik/flutter_app_example/tree/master/notepad_sqflite) that runs on Windows as well as iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Drift is the new version of Floor, it supports all platforms including Windows:
https://pub.dev/packages/drift

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Floor works fine with windows too.
I've used it in many applications, but not in production mode.

Comment: in production mood floor will not works